# Trouble while installing sysbench

Tags: raspbian

I can't install sysbench on my Raspberry 3B+ by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install sysbench
```

It returns to me something like (translated):

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2: Directory or file does not exist)

E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Answer (score 0):

If I try to install without sudo I get:

```
rpi ~$ apt install sysbench
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

That are near exactly the same error messages than you get. So for me it looks like you forget to prepend `sudo` or `sudo` is not working proberly. Check with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo whoami
root
```

If you do not get **root** then you have a serious problem. Superuser **root** does not have a known password so you cannot login as root and fix sudo. The only way I know is to modify `etc/passwd` and `etc/shadow` to clear the root password with the SD Card attached with a card reader to another computer. Then you can boot with this modifications and login as root and may fix sudo.